# Running Time of Dijkstra's Algorithm - Priority Queue (Heap)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dijkstra

I'm having a hard time understanding why the complexity of Dijkstra's Algorithm with a Heap is  O( (m + n)*log(n) ) where m is the number of edges and n is the number of vertices.

My understanding is:

Now I know one has to do n remove mins. (Each remove min takes log(n) from a heap).

Then one has to do m update keys. (Each update key takes log(n)).

Hence the answer. Is my concept clear? Otherwise can you please explain how to get the time complexity of the Dijkstra's Algorithm.

Comment: Complexity of Dijsktra's with heap is O(m+ n*log(n)) (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), not O((m+n) log(n), so your reasoning seems correct.

Comment: I'm not using a Fibonacci Heap.

Comment: This section does the math for other types of heaps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Running_time

Comment: Yes your analysis is correct for a binary heap.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity varies slightly depending on the way you implement Dijkstra using heap. For instance I am using the built-in priority queue in `c++` and this heap does not support priority update. Thus each time I want to update the priority of a given element I simply push one more element in the heap. This may cause my heap to become of size `m`(still each insert/pop has a complexity of `O(log(m))` which is the same as `O(log(n))`).

If you use Fibonacci heap you can reduce the complexity of the algorithm.

If you use a regular binary heap your analysis is pretty much correct - you need to push m elements in a heap that supports insert/pop in `O(log(n))`. You also need to remove the minimum element at least `n` times.